# What does "one plus one, does it make one?" mean in movie Incendies?

Tags: plot-explanation, incendies

In the movie [Incendies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1255953/), when Simon gets to know about his brother from Warlord to tell his sister Jeanne about the brother, he asks her

> "One plus one, does it make one?"

I understood what he was trying to say from his sister's expression and later parts of the movie, but didn't get it at that moment. How does his sister understood what he meant to say by just this phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is my theory that these kids are intelligent and this is the normal way they communicate with each other, kind of like solving puzzles.

**"One plus one, does it make one?"** means they are looking for 2 guys: one is their father and one is their mother's lost child, i.e their elder brother. So from their point of view **1 guy is the Father** and **1 guy is the Elder brother** (from their mother's point of view 1 guy is the Father of her children and 1 guys is her son).  "One plus one, does it make one?" means **"both are the same"**, not like a question or saying that is something which gives them so much weight to take and accept. **1+1=1!**

Comment: I edited this answer but have no idea what the last sentence means. If anyone can make sense of it, please edit it or leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Note : Spoiler**

They had two letters looking for their owners.

Their mother had given them two letters, one to their father and the other to their brother

The meaning of this dialogue is that although there are two letters, the owners of those letters are not two people.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer a little? How are the two envelopes looking for their owners? How are the envelopes' owners not two people. You can use spoiler tags to hide potential spoilers.